# IntellJ debugger: Can I always apply an expression automatically at a breakpoint?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Is there any way in IntelliJ's debugger to always:

a) set result to true or

b) make foo() return true

I know that I can change the variable when I am in a breakpoint, but I want it to happen always and automatically, without changing the code because it is a decompiled class.

```
public void foo() {
   boolean result = false;
   ..
   return result;
}
```

Comment: you could set a watch variable to watch the result of `result=true`... which should do the trick... but ever `result` variable the code encounters would then also be true

Answer (score 1):

Add a breakpoint on the line with `return`, in breakpoint properties unset "suspend", set "evaluate and log" to `result = true`.

If there are more than one `return` in the method, you'll need to modify the `result` value before all of them.

[image]